# Head First Java 2nd Ed- Page 44, Chaper 2

Tags: java

So I'm getting a little bit confused on the pool puzzle in head first java. I cant fully understand yet on how the logic works on this codes.I want to know why the output on this code is 10.

Here is the code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args){
         Echo e1 = new Echo();
         Echo e2 = new Echo();

         int x =0;

         while(x<4){
            e1.hello();
            e1.count += 1;

            if(x==3){
               e2.count +=1;
            }

            if(x>0){
               e2.count =e2.count + e1.count;
            }
            x += 1;
         }

         System.out.println(e2.count);
   }
}
```

Can someone guide me? (Noob here).

Comment: we can´t really tell you as there is no class `Echo` provided. But a good way to find out would be the usage of a debugger and would probably provide a faster answer than we could provide

Comment: @Muffin post the class `Echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following list shows you the states of the variables after each loop:

loop 1:

- x = 0
- e1.count = 1 (line 9)
- e2.count  = 0

loop 2:

- x = 1
- e1.count = 2 (line 9)
- e2. count = 2 (line 16 => `x > 0`)

loop 3:

- x = 2
- e1.count = 3 (line 9)
- e2.count = 2 + 3 = 5 (line 16)

loop 4 (last):

- x = 3
- e1.count = 4 (line 9)
- e2.count = 6 (line 12)
- e2.count = 6 + 4 = 10 (line 16)

Answer (score 0):

I've completed that chapter. So I know what is in ***Echo*** class and what about this problem is. :) Try this code.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Echo e1=new Echo();
        Echo e2=new Echo();

        int x=0;
        while(x<4)
        {
            e1.hello();

            e1.count=e1.count+1;
            if(x==3)
                e2.count=e2.count+1;

            if(x>0)
                e2.count=e2.count+e1.count;
            x++;
        }
        System.out.println(e2.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking why the output is 10. You're answering the exercise for him.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know why the output on this code is 10.

So this line made me to reverse engineer it. and class `Echo` should be similar to below:

```
class Echo
{
     public int count; 
     void hello() { // ... }    
}
```

Add some print statements to your main method to see the flow:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
        Echo e1 = new Echo();
        Echo e2 = new Echo();

        int x =0;
        while(x<4){
            //e1.hello();
            e1.count += 1;
            System.out.println("e1.count = " + e1.count);

        if(x==3){
            e2.count +=1;
            System.out.println("e2.count = " + e2.count);
        }

        if(x>0){
            System.out.println("e2.count = " + e2.count +"+"+ e1.count);
            e2.count =e2.count + e1.count;
            System.out.println("e2.count = "+ e2.count);
        }
        x += 1;
      }
        System.out.println(e2.count);
    }
```